# How can I use my android phone with my pc without installing anything on my phone?

Tags: android, windows-10

My phone's screen broke but it's still functional,I was wondering if there's any software that allows me to use my phone or at least show the screen on my pc.

Comment: I’m not sure, but maybe ADB would work. Though you would have to approve a connection request if you’re running a recent version of Android (maybe attach an external keyboard?).

Comment: If you have an external SD card you can also try to attach that to your PC.

Comment: I'd recommend checking with the [broken-screen tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/broken-screen/info) on our Android sister site, which a.o. covers that topic.

Answer (score 1):

One potential option would be to use ADB, though you might have to approve a connection request. Something like this looks promising (the README even mentions your use case): https://github.com/MajeurAndroid/Adb-Remote-Screen.